# IDA Pro jump to offset of DWORD

Tags: ida

I have the following instruction in IDAs Decompiler:

```
result = data[3 * a1] + ptr;
```

and would like to know what is at the position if a1=60.

So I have to look at data[180]. Unfortunately all I see there is

```
.rodata:EDDCCB10          data   dd 0, 10001h, 2 dup(1), 10001h, 1, 2, 10001h, 1, 3, 10001h
.rodata:EDDCCB10                 dd 1, 4, 10001h, 1, 5, 10001h, 1, 6, 10001h, 1, 7, 10001h
.rodata:EDDCCB10                 dd 1, 8, 10001h, 1, 0Ch, 10004h, 1, 10h, 10004h, 1, 14h
.rodata:EDDCCB10                 dd 10004h, 1, 18h, 10004h, 1, 1Ch, 10004h, 1, 20h, 10004h
.rodata:EDDCCB10                 dd 1, 24h, 10004h, 1, 28h, 10004h, 1, 2Ch, 10010h, 1, 3Ch
.rodata:EDDCCB10                 dd 10040h, 1, 7Ch, 10006h, 1, 82h, 10001h, 1, 84h, 10078h
```

Of course I could just count 180 elements, but is there really no better way to know whats behind data[180] so I can look what the offset bases on ptr is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. Move the cursor to `data` and press `*`. Uncheck `Use "dup" construct` and select `Display indexes` option. You'll get something like this:
[image]